# Exceeded storage allocation. The server response was: 5.3.4 Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, email-attachments

We are sending email using STMP. It is working fine on development machine but when we run the same code on server (window server 2003) it throws below error:

***Exceeded storage allocation. The server response was: 5.3.4 Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size.***

I have google it and found that it is the maximum size limit on server.

How do I change the maximum size on server?

Answer (score 3):

How big emails are you trying to send? The default size limit for an Exchange server is typically 10 MB, but because binary attachments are base64-encoded an attachment of around 7.5 MB is the largest you can send.

Changing the size limit on the server is certainly possible, but the exact procedure for doing that depends on the server software and version used. Exchange servers can be a bit tricky because there are several places where message sizes can be limited. Here is one document, but you can certainly find more by googling:

https://support.mcafeesaas.com/MCAFEE/_cs/AnswerDetail.aspx?sSessionID=&aid=27216